# Putting Text Over an Image in Multi-Item-Carousel in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a multi-item bootstrap carousel and I want to put text in certain parts of the images in this carousel. Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bajYYN) of what I have. Currently, the text will show only when the image is the first one listed. As you can see when you go right once the streamer text appears on the first image, then if you proceed to go back left the text disappears and stays only on the first image.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" id="theCarousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x110/f44336/000000" class="image img-thumbnail img-responsive"></a></div>
                            <div class="image-content">Streamer</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x110/f44336/000000" class="image img-thumbnail img-responsive"></a></div>
                            <div class="image-content">Streamer</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x110/f44336/000000" class="image img-thumbnail img-responsive"></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x110/673ab7/000000" class="image img-thumbnail img-responsive"></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x110/4caf50/000000" class="image img-thumbnail img-responsive"></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x110/8bc34a/000000" class="image img-thumbnail img-responsive"></a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.multi-item-carousel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner > .item {
    transition: 500ms ease-in-out left;
}

.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner .active.left {
    left: -33%;
}

.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner .active.right {
    left: 33%;
}

.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner .next {
    left: 33%;
}

.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner .prev {
    left: -33%;
}

@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
    .multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner > .item {
        transition: 500ms ease-in-out left;
        transition: 500ms ease-in-out all;
        backface-visibility: visible;
        transform: none!important;
    }
}

.multi-item-carousel .carousel-control.left,
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-control.right {
    width: 5%;
    background-image: none!important;
    filter: none!important;
    outline: none!important;
    border: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.carousel {
    padding: 20px 70px;
}

.image {
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}

.image-content {
    top: 5px;
    left: 21px;
    position: absolute;
    color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
    font-size: 11px;
}

body {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: I did, but I couldn't figure out how to make each image's text stay with its image. I tried using the CSS position property but it made the carousel glitch every time you pressed the arrows. @Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the text to appear on certain images, you must put the `div` containing the the text inside of the `col` in which you are placing your image. Check if this is what you are trying to acheive.

```js
// Instantiate the Bootstrap carousel
$('.multi-item-carousel').carousel({
    interval: false
});
  
  // for every slide in carousel, copy the next slide's item in the slide.
  // Do the same for the next, next item.
$('.multi-item-carousel .item').each(function () {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }   
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    if (next.next().length > 0) {
        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    } else {
        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

```css
.multi-item-carousel {
    width: 850px;
    height: 150px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner > .item {
    transition: 500ms ease-in-out left;
}

.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner .active.left {
    left: -33%;
}

.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner .active.right {
    left: 33%;
}

.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner .next {
    left: 33%;
}

.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner .prev {
    left: -33%;
}

@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
    .multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner > .item {
        transition: 500ms ease-in-out left;
        transition: 500ms ease-in-out all;
        backface-visibility: visible;
        transform: none!important;
    }
}

.multi-item-carousel .carousel-control.left,
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-control.right {
    width: 5%;
    background-image: none!important;
    filter: none!important;
    outline: none!important;
    border: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.carousel {
    padding: 20px 70px;
}

.image {
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}

.image-content {
    top: 5px;
    left: 21px;
    position: absolute;
    color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
    font-size: 11px;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" id="theCarousel">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x110/f44336/000000" class="image img-thumbnail img-responsive"></a>
                                  <div class="image-content">Streamer</div>
                                </div>  
                            </div>

                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x110/f44336/000000" class="image img-thumbnail img-responsive"></a>
                                  <div class="image-content">Streamer</div>
                                </div>    
                            </div>

                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x110/f44336/000000" class="image img-thumbnail img-responsive"></a></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x110/673ab7/000000" class="image img-thumbnail img-responsive"></a></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x110/4caf50/000000" class="image img-thumbnail img-responsive"></a></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x110/8bc34a/000000" class="image img-thumbnail img-responsive"></a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: same solution you have :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try using put text separate div to `col-xs-4` div it will be display you content each time like:

```
<div class="item active">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <a href="#1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x110/f44336/000000" class="image img-thumbnail img-responsive">
      </a>
      <!-- here-->
      <div class="image-content">Streamer</div>
      <!-- -->
   </div>
   <!--<div class="image-content">Streamer</div>-->
</div>
```